# Insert dirnames into respectively named filenames in bash

Tags: bash, glob

In my directory I have plenty of `*.yml` files named like:

```
work-arran.yml
work-cap.yml
work-exposed.yml
work-humax.yml
work-instruc.yml
work-kiln.yml
work-lex.yml
work-merc.yml
```

and also directories with same names but using underscores instead of dashes:

```
work_cap
work_exposed
work_humax
work_instruc
work_kiln
work_lex
work_merc
```

I want to put yaml record `grid_pool: dir_name_here` into each respective
`*.yml` file automatically, where dir_name_here would be the name of each
file's respective directory.

Tried with this, and while it would work it appended desired line into
underscored version of *.yml file instead of exsisting dashed.

How to change that last `fn.yml` so it replaces again `_` for `-`?

```
ls *.yml | sed 's/-/_/g' | sed 's/.yml//g' | xargs -n1 -I fn bash -c "echo '  grid_pool: fn' >> fn.yml"
```

Comment: [You should not use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: this is just onetime oneliner

Comment: Still, the `ls` in `ls *.yml` is pointless; the shell expands the wildcard, and `ls` adds nothing of value (and potentially adds stuff which is of negative value) after the shell already produced the list of matches.  The link explains all the things which can go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter expansion with substitution:

```
for file in *.yml ; do
    dirname=${file/-/_}
    echo "  grid_pool: ${dirname%.yml}" >> "$file"
done
```

You can use the same method with `xargs` but I fear it'll be slower, as it starts a new shell for each file:

```
... | xargs -I fn bash -c 's=fn; echo "  grid_pool: fn" >> ${s/_/-}.yml'
```

Comment: Is it possible to strip `.yml` in one go, along with replacing `-` for `_`?

Comment: You need two steps to perform substitutions in different parts of the variable value.

Comment: just for curiousity, is it possible to resolve that second `fn` in what I have been trying?

Comment: `$file` already contains the value you are trying to write into, but certainly, you can use something like `${file%.yml}.yml` to strip off the `.yml` and then immediately add it back.